# Convert Hald CLUT image to 3DLut file (*.3dl, *.cude)

Tags: python, image, colors, imagemagick, blender

Only recently I found [Hald CLUT technology](http://www.quelsolaar.com/technology/clut.html) to process images and it was very useful.

How can I  convert **Hald CLUTs** created by me to other formats and use it everywhere, in other image editors.

- How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert HALD CLUT to Cube format online at http://filterhunt.com.

Answer (score 0):

3dl file is essentially an ASCII file. Its header consists of a chain of numbers (tab separated) increasing in equal distance from 0 to 255 (0 to (2^8)-1 for 8 bit depth) or 0 to 4095 (for a 12 bit depth).

```
    0   17  34  51  68  85  102 119 136 153 170 187 204 221 238 255
```

the following lines are the RGB values for each point, tab separated, grouped by three in a line. With blue channel changing the fastest, followed by green and red.

```
    6   4   5
    7   5   9
    9   5   14
    8   4   18
    7   5   25
    7   5   39
... etc.
```

3dl format spec: http://download.autodesk.com/us/systemdocs/pdf/lustre_color_management_user_guide.pdf

You can convert any Hald CLUT or other color transform by just applying it onto the Hald CLUT that has swapped R channel with B channel (default Hald CLUT increases the red channel first, green the second and blue as a last one - thus you need to swap the red with blue for *.3dl compatibility with BGR order). Then you just export this file as an ASCII *.ppm and change the indentation with some text editor, so that the values are grouped by 3, separated by a single tabulation character. For the *.3dl header you want to use the blue channel values of the top left row from the identity Hald CLUT. To apply indentation for larger LUTs you need either some macro recording capability or process the *.ppm file with some script.

I've made a video tutorial 'Convert Hald CLUT to 3D LUT (*.3dl) for free' on how to perform the conversion using just image editor allowing to same images to ASCII file format (*.ppm), a text editor and keyboard macro recording: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIbHOAdHXr0
I hope somebody finds it useful.